# Appending each element of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append

I need to append each element of a matrix in for a loop. 
Let's say I have a matrix

```
1 Step : [[x,x],[x,x]],
2 Step : [[y,y],[y,y]],
3 Step : [[z,z],[z,z]]
  ........... N
```

Output should be

```
[[x,y,z......, x,y,z......,], [x,y,z......, x,y,z......,]]
```

```
L=3
N=2
VB=[]
for nstep in np.arange(N):
    V=[]
    for i in range(0,L):
        U=[]
        for j in range(0,L):
            m=3*i+4*j*nstep
            U.append(m)
        V.append(U)
    VB.append(V)
K=np.array(VB)
```

K is (2,3,3), I want to (1,3,3,2).

Thanks in advace.

Comment: There are missing variables in your code snippet. But regarding first part of you question it seems like you need something like `ans = np.empty((2, 4)); a[:, ::2] = np.zeros((2, 2)); a[:, 1::2] = np.ones((2, 2))` which gives `[[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]`?

Comment: It will not help Ayrat. Because I need it in a for loop. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: If you must do things in a loop, work with lists (even nested lists).  You can create the array from the nested lists at the end.  Don't attempt to use `np.append` (especially not iteratively).